# Make a bootable WinPE

Tags: boot, windows-pe

My question is not exactly what the subject suggests..

I got a couple of files that I believe are WinPE files + a .WIM image..

Here is the folder tree:

[image]

The **OS12.wim** file is 5-GB in size.

Inside the **boot** folder there's a BCD and BOOT.SDI files.

Inside the **sources** folder there's a boot.wim file.

My question is how do I put all that on a bootable DVD or USB?

Answer (score 0):

Might be easier to describe what you're trying to do.

The Windows Automated Installation Kit has utilities (copype.cmd, oscdimg.exe) to build bootable PE media.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at BartPE.

http://www.nu2.nu/pebuilder/

Answer (score 0):

Bootable USB: Format with NTFS on a Vista/7/2008/R2 machine, then copy the files over.
Making a bootable CD is slightly more complicated....